# makefile can't find .o file

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm working on a simple makefile using implicit rules, and not really understanding how make is deciding its execution order. When I have my makefile setup like this, it says it can't find Wave.o:

```
CXX = g++

AudioSample: Wave.o AudioSample.o 
    $(CXX) -o AudioSample AudioSample.o Wave.o

AudioSample.o: Wave.h PCADPCM.h
    $(CXX) -c AudioSample.cpp

Wave.o: Wave.h
```

Terminal output:

```
g++ -o AudioSample AudioSample.o Wave.o
g++: error: Wave.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [AudioSample] Error 1
```

However when I change the order of the targets it works fine:

```
AudioSample: Wave.o AudioSample.o 
    $(CXX) -o AudioSample AudioSample.o Wave.o

Wave.o: Wave.h

AudioSample.o: Wave.h PCADPCM.h
    $(CXX) -c AudioSample.cpp
```

Terminal output:

```
g++    -c -o Wave.o Wave.cpp
g++ -c AudioSample.cpp
g++ -o AudioSample AudioSample.o Wave.o
```

Whats the problem??

Comment: _`Wave.o: Wave.h`_ So usually you don't compile `.h` files. If you don't have a corresponding translation unit (`.cpp`), that header probably is defined all inline. Just omit a `Wave.o` file from your objects list.

Comment: What version of make are you seeing this with? I can't reproduce this with the versions of GNU make I've tried (3.81, 3.82, 4.0, 4.1).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He has a `Wave.cpp` file it seems. It is listed in the working output snippet at the end.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, looks like. Though that rule seems to be wrong (I've updated my comment). /OT BTW do you have suitable testbeds for such quick multiple version tests as you've mentioned in your comment. I would be interested in such. If you won't bother, you can sent me some hints at that e-mail address from my profile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Wave.o: Wave.h` has no recipe. It won't cause `Wave.h` to be compiled or anything. It simply lists `Wave.h` as a prerequisite of `Wave.o` so that if `Wave.h` changes `Wave.o` will be recompiled automatically. That's quite likely to be correct.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've just got them all built on my development machine to test quick things like this. So I just run `make-$version`.

Comment: @EtanReisner OK, of course. And default to the latest. I'm doing similar stuff with compiler toolchains :-), stupid question.

Comment: I default to 3.81 actually because that's what my platform has but I needed to test things in newer versions over the past few years to confirm things (both here and for my own usage).

Comment: I believe you are missing `.cpp` filenames in your list of dependencies.  I'd like my `makefile` to generate a `.o` from a `.cpp` if the `cpp` file changed, not only if the `.h*` files changed.

Comment: I am using version 3.81.  Some of you have said I'm missing the Wave.cpp file.  But that should be found by an implicit rule. Secondly, its working fine when I list the Wave.o target before the AudioSample.o target.  But, to me, the order of the targets listed in the make file should not make a difference and yet it is making a difference.

Comment: If you are having problems troubleshooting make scripts, one thing you can do is add --debug to your make invocations.  This lets you see what is going through make's brain while it is thinking about your recipes.  It is a lot of data, but can teach you a lot about what actually happens when you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check for Tabs vs Spaces in your `Makefile`.

For example with Vim editor, you can search for tabs `/\t` or add the following to your config:

```
" in ~/.vimrc
listchars=tab:»»,trail:·,nbsp:~
set list
```

You clearly have a **hidden Tab** in the `Wave.o` rule (shown like in my editor):

```
Wave.o : Wave.h
»»»»»»
```

This *tab* breaks implicit rules to generate `Wave.o`. Remove extra Tabs and it will be fine like your second `Makefile` where there is no room for Tab as the target is the very last line of file.

For information, `Wave.h` is a *prerequisite* and is not used by `make` to guess the source file name (`Wave.cpp` in this case). Even `Wave.o : Wave.cpp` wouldn't have helped.